# Unable to access an http sevice forwarded using ssh

Tags: linux, networking, ssh, port-forwarding

I forwarded a port from a remote server (which has Tomcat running on it) to a local port on my machine.

Say, if the remote server address is http://myremoteserver.com:8080, I forwarded the port to localhost this way:

ssh -L 8080:myremoteserver.com:8080 -N watson

Note: Access to myremoteserver is possible only through watson.

After forwarding, if I run localhost:8080 on my browser, I can see the output. But if I try to access this localhost from any other machine on my network (DNS of localhost is server1) through browser, say server1:8080, it does not load at all.

Strangely, if I run tomcat on localhost (instead of port forwarding through ssh), and access it through browser from another machine on network, server1:8080, it works.

Please help. I thought it has to do something with iptables; but it doesn't work even after turning it off.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
ssh -L *:8080:myremoteserver.com:8080 -N watson
```

excerpt from `man ssh` for option `-L`:

> ```
> By default, the local port is bound in accordance with the GatewayPorts setting.
> However, an explicit bind_address may be used to bind the connection to a specific address.
> The bind_address of “localhost” indicates that the listening port be bound for local use 
> only, while an empty address or ‘*’ indicates that the port should be available from 
> all interfaces.
> ```